# Emacs and Pandoc: can't create a pdf

Tags: emacs, pandoc

I use GNU Emacs in a Mac. After installing the last version of Pandoc I can't create pdf files. Pandoc works well when I use the Terminal. I think that the problem has to do with the fact that Emacs doesn't find the template default.latex. This template is in my `~/.pandoc/templates`.

This is the error message I receive when trying to create a pdf:
pandoc: `/usr/local/share/pandoc-1.10.1/data/templates/default.latex: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)`

I don't understand why Emacs is trying to find `default.latex` here.

Comment: Perhaps your latest version of pandoc has a new folder name and you need to readjust your path to include the new folder containing the pandoc executable.  Here is an example of what I use for texlive:  `(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/texbin"))`  So you need to find out where your new pandoc was installed to.

Comment: @lawlist My pandoc v.1.12.3 is installed in `/usr/local/bin/pandoc`. I have also an older version v.1.10.1 in `usr/bin`. Pandoc works (almost) well from Emacs because I can convert files from it. The only thing that doesn't work is the conversion to pdf files.

Comment: I would try putting this in my `.emacs` file and see if that helps:  `(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/bin/pandoc"))`

Comment: To be of more assistance, we would need to know how it is that you instruct pandoc to generate your latex file.  For example, are you using `pandoc-mode`?:  http://joostkremers.github.io/pandoc-mode/

Comment: The other thing you can do is open up Terminal.app in the Applications folder of OSX and type `echo $PATH`.  You may find that your old pandoc folder comes up.  If so, then you can remove that -- OSX uses a variety of locations to set the path -- e.g., on Snow Leopard, there are four common locations where these things are set: `/private/etc/paths`; `/private/etc/paths.d/X11`; `~/.bash_profile`; and `~/.profile`

Comment: @lawlist I am using pandoc-mode. My path (`.bash_profile`) is `/Users/sbacelar2/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin`. As I have two version of pandoc I changed the order of `usr/local/bin` with `usr\bin`and tried to create a pdf in pandoc-mode. Emacs used the older version of pandoc but couldn't create a pdf. I think that the problem is that there is no `pandoc-1.10.1`in `usr/local/share/`.

Comment: How about `echo $PATH` -- what is the output from Terminal.app?  `.bash_profile` is just one of four that I mentioned.  `echo $PATH` from Terminal.app will give you a complete list of everything natively setup on OSX.  While you are at it, go ahead and grep the likely suspects on your hard-drive for `pandoc-1.10.1` -- you need to track down where that setting is.  And, while you are at it, also do an `echo $PATH` from within an Emacs buffer like `M-x eshell` -- the result will be different than the one you do from Terminal.app.

Comment: @lawlist I tried to modify init.el as you wrote before (`setenv "PATH"...`) and nothing happened with emacs. Emacs tries to find the same file in `/usr/local/share`. A file that doesn't exist.

Comment: The path I sent is the output from `echo $PATH`. I also have done `echo $PATH` from Emacs but the path is the same plus at the end `/usr/local/bin/pandoc`because I changed `init.el`file. I already know that I have an old version of pandoc in `usr/bin`: pandoc version 1.10.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(setq pandoc-binary "/usr/local/bin/pandoc")
```

This answer assumes you do not have a folder named `pandoc` inside of `/usr/local/bin/` and that the actual executable has an absolute path of `/usr/local/bin/pandoc`.  If the executable is buried deeper in another folder or more, then adjust the path in this example accordingly.  The code at the top of this answer goes in your `.emacs` file.

You may also wish to modify this variable depending upon your preferred setup:

```
(setq pandoc-data-dir "~/.emacs.d/pandoc-mode/")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Setting `pandoc-binary`in `init.el` answered my question.

Comment: Great -- glad to help.  Please place a check-mark on the answer to mark this thread as being resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve a more general solution using [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell):

> A GNU Emacs library to ensure environment variables inside Emacs look the same as in the user's shell.

Just install it, require it (only if your aren't using MELPA) in your `.emacs` file and add this line to it:

```
(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
```

For more information see the [usage section in the README](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell#usage).