# emacs cannot find pandoc.exe

Tags: emacs, markdown, pandoc

I have been attempting to use pandoc mode with markdown mode to generate latex pdf through pandoc.  However, attempts to run pandoc (C-c / with r) give the message that pandoc.exe has been moved.  This is because pandoc is looking in the wrong directory in the first place, my pandoc was installed through choclatey to C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\pandoc.exe.  Can someone advise me how to get emacs to look in the right place?

I have attempted to use the below code as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791097/emacs-and-pandoc-cant-create-a-pdf).  This has not worked.

```
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'pandoc-mode)
(setq pandoc-binary "C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/pandoc")
```

Comment: You should probably add `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin` to your Path.  Emacs should pick up the Path environment variable, but if not you can edit env vars in Emacs with `getenv`/`setenv`.

Answer (score 1):

I already had a similar problem and found a very detailed explanation of how to do it [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27110/markdown-preview-in-emacs-using-pandoc).
Basically, you need to open your `.md` file with emacs, type `M-x customize-mode` (I don't know if you know, but M-x is Alt+x), search for `Markdown Command` and type the command you want emacs to run, with all your preferred pandoc flags. For example, my `Markdown Command` has the command `/home/myusername/Softwares/pandoc-2.6/bin/pandoc --to=latex` (I'm on Linux). I prefer using full paths or create aliases, because I usually have multiple versions of the same program and putting them in the path environment variable does not work, but if you have only one pandoc version you can just put it into the path environment variable like @jpkotta suggested.

Comment: I'm hesitant to try this and break the machine as it is. I don't know what I did but it suddenly started working after re-installing emacs a while back.  if anyone comments that this worked for them, ill make sure to say this is an answer.

Comment: This is not a dangerous solution, if you decide to remove pandoc or move it to another directory, just do the same steps and change de directory, or put it in the environment variable